# Define field type with add_fields processor in filebeat.yml?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, filebeat

Looking at [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/7.4/add-fields.html) documentation on adding fields, I see that filebeat can add any custom field by name and value that will be appended to every documented pushed to Elasticsearch by Filebeat.

This is defined in filebeat.yml:

```
processors:
- add_fields:
    target: project
    fields:
      name: myproject
      id: '574734885120952459'
```

Is there a way, strictly from filebeat.yml, to give fields added here a "type" as well? For example, can I assign "name" to type "keyword" ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've seen to accomplish does not involve filebeat.yml, but creating a custom fields.yml file in the filebeat directory (this all applies for any beat) with the field and type specified under the "beat" key.

Example, if field "id" above was declared in filebeat.yml, and we wanted it to be a custom field of type "keyword," we would do the following:

copy fields.yml to my_filebeat_fields.yml file in the filebeat directory.
In my_filebeat_fields, add in this section:

```
- key: beat
  anchor: beat-common
  title: Beat
  description: >
    Contains common beat fields available in all event types.
  fields:
    # your customization begins here:
    - name: id
    - type: keyword
```

Then do the following to use this new custom fields file:

Modify this portion of filebeat.yml to include:

```
#==================== Elasticsearch template setting ==========================

setup.template.name: "filebeat-*"
setup.template.fields: "my_filebeat_fields.yml"
setup.template.overwrite: true
```

then load the template into elastic in whichever method is appropriate for your environment, following [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-template.html).

(Assuming version 7.x for everything)

EDIT:

Apparently setting "setup.template.append_fields" option in the filebeat.yml file could also work, but I have not explored that.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-template.html

Comment: why does the key have to be "beat"? Do you have a reference for that?